# What should I store on my external SD card?

Tags: external-sd

I have a 64G SD card to install (my first). I'd like to get a good chunk of my music collection there. What type of content make sense (efficiency) to move...or what things should I NOT move?

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's a good quality, fast card (class 4, 6, or 10), you can store *everything* on it from your apps to music, pictures, and video files, and even record HD video and take high MP pictures directly on to it. You should notice a significant increase in read/write speeds depending on the class of the card.

Comment: Thanks SeanPercy42. Telling me what "can" be stored is somewhat helpful, but my question is, what "should" be stored? In real life, I keep large stuff in the garage, food in the kitchen, toiletries in the washroom, etc. What makes most (or least) sense on the card?

Another way to ask is, what would take the most burden off the original storage, if it were to be moved to external?

Comment: On digital storage like MicroSD cards, Solid State drives, and smartphone internal storage (digital as well), there is no 'taking burden' off of them. You could have your internal storage 98% full and it would still perform just as well as it would if it was 2% full. The only reason people store files on MicroSD cards is to *save space* on the internal storage because **many** apps can't be moved to external storage and you want to keep the space free for them. You **should** move everything you possibility can to external storage, especially huge files. You don't want to move widgets though.

Comment: Hey Sylar, I was unable to edit my last comment but I wanted to clarify one thing. I said it doesn't matter if the storage is 98% full, but it does (to Android). For some reason Android starts bugging you about low disk space around 80%, so just try to keep your internal storage below 70% at all times and you'll be fine. Also, if you decide to move any of your apps to your MicroSD, be sure not to move widgets. They need to stay on internal storage to function properly. I just store my data files on mine (pics, vids, docs, offline maps, and music) maybe a big game or two.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use too many widgets but I'll keep that in mind.  Is there a way to know  which apps can/cannot be moved?

Comment: Yep, download [AppMgr III] (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=pt_BR). It's got a nice, user-friendly, theme-able interface that shows the apps you can move on the far left screen, apps currently on your external SD on the middle screen, and apps that are 'phone only' on the right screen. There are other apps like it if you don't like that one for any reason. Just look under the similar apps section on the same page as that app. Good luck!